# Looking for a specific paper not available electronically

Tags: reference-request, numerical-linear-algebra

not really sure that it is the right place to post, but I'll give it a go. I really would love to have a look to this technical report

J.G. Lewis, *Algorithms for Sparse Matrix Eigenvalue Problems*, Report **STAN-CS-77-595**, Computer Science Department, Stanford University, Stanford, California, March 1977.

It's not available as a PDF on their web-page, I was just wondering if anyone had ever come accross it. Any suggestion on how I might get it?

Thanks a lot,
Sebastien

Comment: Did you try inter-library loan at your local university library? Alternatively here's [the proQuest entry](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=908396) (or [try this](http://proquest.umi.com/pqdlink?did=760512971)) where you can order it (horrendously expensive - the cheapest variant is \$49 but your institute/advisor might have possibilities to finance that).

Comment: Yes, I think I'll have to do that. I was hoping to spare some time, since inter-library loan is quite slow here (not mentioning the fact that the library is closed in august).

Comment: Another option is to try e-mailing either the original author or the Computer Science department at Stanford to see if they can make a scanned copy available for you. Most of the times when I wrote to authors for copies of their papers, I get very nice responses (sometimes even physical copies).